# i have two source and destination directories i need to find how to create the relative link from source to destination path

Tags: perl

I have two directories in which source and destination is there

For example,

- `/nfs/edu/lib/etc/sim/win` --- this is my destination
- `/nfs/edu/lib/etc/ket/ops/nis` ---- this is source

I already tried Perl's `abs2rel` function to convert the above relpath from source but it is not giving the exact answer, it is giving me 
`../../../../sim/win` -- this is the output I'm getting now

```perl
my $rel_path = File::Spec->abs2rel( $modules_dir ,$project_dir) ;
```

The project directory is source and module directory is destination

I need to create relative path from source to destination.
My output should be like `../../../sim/win` -- this is from source to destination.

Comment: Why do you think the output from `abs2rel` is incorrect?

Comment: @tripleee when I use abs2rel it is giving me some relative path but not specific to the source path it is generalized one.. ../../../sim/win this is what I'm expecting but ../../../../sim/win this is what I got

Comment: You will want to [edit] your question into a [mre] with exactly the values which produce this result. The general lack of explicitness is still problematic here.

Comment: Consider also [relative from Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#relative) which handles some edge cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think your program is:

```
use v5.10;
use File::Spec;

my $modules_dir = "/nfs/edu/lib/etc/sim/win";
my $project_dir = "/nfs/edu/lib/etc/ket/ops/nis";

my $rel_path = File::Spec->abs2rel( $modules_dir, $project_dir );
say $rel_path;
```

The output is what you want:

```
../../../sim/win
```

However, you don't provide the program you're actually running so we don't have any hope of seeing why you get a different answer. Always post the minimal, complete, and actual code that demonstrates the issue.

But, I suspect that you are going about this problem in the wrong way. Typically, I would rather have absolute paths instead of relative ones. If I know the absolute path I always know where something is going. If I have a relative path, I also have to know (and maybe constantly adjust) the current working directory.

For example, in this program, I can be in any directory that I like and still move the file to the right place:

```
use v5.10;
use File::Spec;

my $modules_dir = "/nfs/edu/lib/etc/sim/win";
my $project_dir = "/nfs/edu/lib/etc/ket/ops/nis";

my $file = "some_library.pl";

my $source = File::Spec->catfile( $project_dir, $file );
my $dest   = File::Spec->catfile( $modules_dir, $file );

rename $source => $dest or warn "Could not rename file: $!";
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and I think this answer is very much capable for my problem and the above program is clear for the understanding, thank you so much for the quick help :)